# Cannot add Bar Button to Second Page through Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder

My App has two pages, so in interface builder I have three controllers:

- A NavigationController
- segues via RootViewController to TableViewController1
- segues via push to TableViewController2

I easily added a Bar Button to the right side of the navigation bar of TableViewController1 by dragging it from the tools.

Tried to do the same thing in TableViewController2 and it won't drop the bar button.

I have the "Shows Navigation Bar" attribute checked on the Navigation Controller and I can see a space for the navigation bar on TableViewController2, but I don't see the same "Navigation Item" in the component hierarchy that I see for TableViewController1.

If I drag a bar button to the controller itself it puts a new NavigationItem icon on the controller (between First Responder and Exit) and that looks promising, but it doesn't show when I run the app.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this TableViewController2, you have to explicitly add a navigation item into the xib and then you can add bar button items on it.[image]

It will look like this in xib , you can set title and button.[image]

Comment: That worked!
I'm realizing that the New Project Wizard setup TableViewController1, and it probably did that for me.  So my problem has nothing to do with the first versus the second page.

Comment: This answer stopped me pulling my hair out.

Comment: I can't believe how obscure this is! Thanks.

Comment: Very obscure indeed! In my case I had a TableViewController segued from the NavigationController and rather than expected (to be able to add a navigation item there to the navigation bar where all the options are actually located for title font size, colour, etc.) I had to instead drag it into the top of the TableViewController. Sheesh. And even then, I still had to add my own back button.